# Convert String variable value to literal

Tags: c#, variables, type-conversion

I wanted to convert a string variable to a literal. For example,

```
string parametervalue= "+";
```

i want to convert this string variable to a literal so that i can use

```
int total = valueA (parametervalue) valueB;
```

so it should be called at runtime as

```
total = valueA + valueB
```

But how to conver the string variable to a literal . What is the method to do this

Appriciate your help.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do this in C# - you are basically asking for extented metaprogramming cababilites here

Comment: the obvious way to do something similar would be `Func<int,int,int> add = (a,b) => a+b; int total = add(valueA, valueB)`

Comment: oh that is helpful. thank you :) i would probably use the alternative method you suggest .

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you? When parametervalue comes from a user, it must be validated.

```
 switch (parametervalue)
        {
            case "+":
                total = valueA + valueB;
                break;

            case "-":
                total = valueA - valueB;
                break;

            case "*":
                total = valueA * valueB;
                break;

            case "/":
                total = valueA / valueB;
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using an extension method

```
public static double Calculate(this string operation, int x, int y)
        {
            switch (operation)
            {
                case "+": return x + y;
                case "-": return x - y;
                case "*": return x * y;
                case "/": return x / y;
                default: throw new Exception("invalid operator");
            }
        }
```

Then you can use it like this `var result = parametervalue.Calculate(valueA, valueB);`

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately C# dose not support what you are asking.

but there is some thing that is close to what you want which is available on C# 6 and makes playing with strings a bit easier.

this is called String Interpolation, here is an example:

```
var x = $"\{this.FirstName} \{this.LastName}"
```

where FirstName and LastName are variables.
read more about it in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)